# How to create a log log plot

Tags: algorithm, analysis

I'm doing algorithm analysis and would like to create a log log plot in Excel/Google docs or anywhere that's good. I've tried in Excel but can't seem to get it to work, and can't seem to find help material for this anywhere, does anyone here know how to get this done?

Comment: In a search using google for "log log plot excel", all the first page results are relevant to your question and should be sufficient to provide you with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't have access to a search engine...using excel...

```
Select your data
Insert it in a plot (for example a scatter plot)
Right click the plot axes and select 'Format Axis'
Check the Logarithm Scale tick box
```